# Javascript execute once

Tags: javascript

How do i get a javascript code to only execute or be used once? example is

```
var stringToMatch = 'christopher';
function toggle (){   

 var input = document.getElementById('text').value; 

 if (input == stringToMatch){  
    document.getElementById('divColor1').style.display = 'block';   
}   
else {   
   document.getElementById('divColor1').style.display = 'none';   
}   
}
```

this code or stringToMatch i want to execute once, after that i dont care if it is deleted in the sense. for this is for coupons. and i am making multiples of this, so once someone has typed this i want it to delete

Comment: let me better phrase now that i see adding two of these only makes the second one work. i want to make we will say 100 coupon codes. 'christopher' being the example used here. once someone hits redeem it takes 'christopher' out of the coupons list. and the others are still there. is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, you could overwrite `toggle()` with an empty function.

```
if (input == stringToMatch){  
    document.getElementById('divColor1').style.display = 'block';   
    window.toggle = function() { };
}
```

Comment: i dont understand this sorry. I also tried a switch a
switch (stringToMatch)
  {
  case 0:
    x="Today it's Sunday";
    break;
  case 1:
    x="Today it's Monday";
    break;
  case 2:
    x="Today it's Tuesday";
    break;
  case 3:
    x="Today it's Wednesday";
    break;
  case 4:
    x="Today it's Thursday";
    break;
  case 5:
    x="Today it's Friday";
    break;
  case 6:
    x="Today it's Saturday";
    break;
to try and change the coupon "name" to more than just one. which it did not work. basically I want once 'christopher' is used its deleted. then if any of the others used they

Comment: as well. I know this is a burden and im probably a hassel lol. Im just tryin to get this code to work the way i need it to